# How to compile pmars-0.9.2 on Ubuntu 18.04? error: Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to compile a pmars-0.9.2 game, but stumbled on an error while passing the test, after command `make -j4`:

`make[2]: *** [extractor/CMakeFiles/extractor.dir/backoff_sampler.cc.o] Error 1
 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2561: recipe for target 'extractor/CMakeFiles/extractor.dir/all' failed
 make[1]: *** [extractor/CMakeFiles/extractor.dir/all] Error 2
 Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
 make: *** [all] Error 2`

Can you tell me which installation drivers are missing to successfully complete the compilation?

Answer (score 0):

To view logs from an unpacked archived use command:

`nano /home/user/Desktop/pmars-0.9.2/cdec/BUILDING`

---

To build cdec, you'll need:

- boost headers & boost program_options (you may need to install a package
  like libboost-dev)

### Instructions for building

1) Create a build directory and generate Makefiles using CMake

```
    mkdir my_build
    cd my_build
    cmake ..

If the cmake command completes successfully, you can proceed. If you have
libraries (such as Boost) installed in nonstandard locations, you may need
to run cmake with special options like -DBOOST_ROOT=/path/to/boost.
```

2) Build

```
    make -j 2
```

3) Test
        make test
        ./tests/run-system-tests.pl

---